# MySql procedure error:1242

Tags: mysql, mysql-error-1242

i'm beginer in sql..
i want make procedure acting like sequence in oracle
Making procedure, i meet error: 1242... please help me~

---

1. target Table

   > CREATE TABLE id_generator (
   >
   > > ```
   > >    seq_currval INT(8) UNSIGNED NOT NULL, 
   > >    org_code varchar(4) not null
   > > ```
   > >
   > > );
2. procedure

   > delimiter $$
   >
   > DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS sp_seq$$
   >
   > CREATE PROCEDURE sp_seq( IN org_code varchar(4), OUT parma1 VARCHAR(11) )
   >
   > > BEGIN
   > >
   > > > ```
   > > >    DECLARE year   VARCHAR(1);
   > > >    DECLARE month   VARCHAR(2);
   > > >    DECLARE seq_current int;
   > > >    SET year = '5';
   > > >    SET month = '01';
   > > >    SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ COMMITTED;
   > > > ```

   ```
      START TRANSACTION;

      SET seq_current = (select seq_currval 
                         from id_generator 
                         where org_code = org_code);
      update id_generator 
      set seq_currval = seq_current + 1 where org_code = org_code;

      COMMIT;

      SET seq_current = seq_current + 1;

      select CONCAT(year, month ,seq_current);
   ```

   > > END $$
   >
   > delimiter ;
3. after call procedure, i found erroe: 1242:

   > CALL sp_seq('1234');
   >
   > > --> ERROR : Error Code: 1242. Subquery returns more than 1 row

Comment: something's wrong with your subquery where you're setting seq_current (as it's returning more than one row).  I'm not familiar enough with mysql syntax, but I'm guessing it's got something to do with the parameter name you're using...try changing it to for example, vorg_code (datatype, then variable name)

Answer (score 0):

This query

```
SET seq_current = (select seq_currval 
                      from id_generator 
                      where org_code = org_code);
```

returns more than one record and can't be stored in a single variable.

```
where org_code = org_code
```

is always true. Rename your input parameter to something else than your column name. Otherwise the DB can't distinguish them.

Answer (score 0):

This query

```
select seq_currval 
                      from id_generator 
                      where org_code = org_code
```

always returns all rows it similar to 1=1

Change it to:

```
select seq_currval 
                      from id_generator 
                      where id_generator.org_code = org_code
```